# Error establishing a database connection

Tags: posts, wp-admin

I was in the midst deleting trash file and the internet connection is becoming really slow. When I clicked the Products tab in the wp-admin it says that: "Error establishing a database connection", although I did not change anything on the database. Also, there are times that the message: "Access to the webpage was denied" is appearing. I've restarted several times, and tried copying and pasting the link in different browsers, but its still appearing and I wonder why. Hope you guys can get me out of this stuff. I think I'm gonna broke down into pieces now. :(

Comment: verify that it's not an issue with your host. do you have command line or phpmyadmin access that can verify your database server is up?

Comment: no, i do not have any phpmyadmin access available and that's another problem. :(

Comment: can you post a link to verify ? 
Unless your server is on a local machine (testing ) Starting and restarting will not help a DB error connection, nor does the browser matters .
"Access to the webpage was denied"  is another problem , but both appears to be a server problem, and not your browser or Personal Computer.

Comment: What host and hosting plan are you using?

Comment: i can't give you the direct link because as of now the errors are also appearing there. i was also thinking that the database might be edited or corrupted.

Comment: i use bluehost.

Comment: that was the the point of asking the link .. so we could check the errors ...

Comment: http://dev.freelanceu.net/ajb/sheepskin/sheepskin-car-seat-covers/acura/seat-type-1/ and also http://dev.freelanceu.net/ajb/sheepskin/. kindly check these links.

Comment: also check this one ---> http://dev.freelanceu.net/ajb/sheepskin/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=wpsc-variation&post_type=wpsc-product&s=text

Comment: i got another message and it says: [an error occurred while processing this directive].

Comment: solved it myself. the wp-admin account itself when used by two individuals at the same time makes the internet connection slow and also the same when the messages are appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging into FTP and making sure there is no .maintenance file, also erase the upgrade folder. Its never a good idea to stop wordpress during an automatic update. Take a look at your wp-config file to make sure everything appears correct, it could of been editing it and you cut it off half way.

Comment: i just checked the FTP and it seems that the everything is correct in the wp-config file. Deleting the upgrade folder does not help since it do have any contents. Anyway, where can I find the .maintenance files?